# Project data out of an immutable map to a different shape

Tags: immutable.js

I have a `Map` of immutable objects with a structure like:

```
id1: {
    someField: 'anyvalue',
    description: 'description1'
},
id2: {
    someField: 'anotherValue`,
    description: 'description2'
}
```

I want to project a `List` of the descriptions without resorting to `toJS()`:

```
[ 'description1', 'description2' ]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = new Immutable.Map({id1: {
    someField: 'anyvalue',
    description: 'description1'
},
id2: {
    someField: 'anotherValue',
    description: 'description2'
}});

const out = data.valueSeq().map(v => v.description).toList();
console.log(out)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

Comment: I believe `valueSeq` provides immutable objects, so mapping from there should be `.map(v => v.get('description')`